Надо добавить видео в тг бот
помогите пожалуйста с решением этой задачи:
Надо добавить видео ("vide/ant.mp4") в тг бот. Я много что перепробовал, но ошибки
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
    def callback_message(callback):
    
        
    
     markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
#Вот сюда
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='afdu'))
            bot.edit_message_text('<b>Анти Оли </b> \n \n Сложность - среднее \n \n Элименты \n Выходы' ,  callback.message.chat.id , callback.message.message_id ,  parse_mode='html' , reply_markup=markup)


что значит "добавить видео"? добавить куда?

https://pytba.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_video

Для отправки видео в библиотеке telebot стоит воспользоваться методом send_video
Например: bot.send_video(user_id, video=open('path', 'r')) про остальные параметры можно прочитать на официальной документации
